# Как создать проект на java 14

Tags: java, пакет, проект

Есть абсолютно пустой репозиторий на java 14, создаю папки, пытаюсь запустить HelloWorld - не работает. Как создавать пакеты, модули? куда класть библиотеки?

Answer (score 0):

Ну, удобнее всего это делать через IDE) На примере Eclipse: File -> New -> Java Project. После создания самого проекта, в папке scr создаем пакеты (если не создать, то будет пакет по умолчанию (default)). При создании, среда разработки сама предложит создать модуль.

С Maven проектом концепция идентичная, только там по-больше настроек)

Для подключения внешних библиотек нужно нажать правой кнопкой мыши по папке с проектом (в IDE), далее Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries